# PHP errors when trying to zip files on server

Tags: php, zip

I've inherited a script to create a .zip file of chosen files (from checkboxes). It works absolutely fine on my local machine, and other peoples local machines. But as soon as we try and put it on a live server (we've tried two). I'm getting errors...

```
    <?php
    function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path){
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        //create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
        if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
            exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
        }
        //add each files of $file_name array to archive
        foreach($file_names as $files)  {
            $zip->addFile($file_path.$files,$files);
        }
        $zip->close();
        $zipped_size = filesize($archive_file_name);
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");// some browsers need this
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Content-Length:". " $zipped_size");
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile("$archive_file_name");
        unlink("$archive_file_name"); // Now delete the temp file (some servers need this option)
        exit;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) {
        //$file_names=$_POST['items'];// Always sanitize your submitted data!!!!!!
        //$file_names = filter_var_array($_POST['items']);//works but it's the wrong method
        $filter = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS) ;
        $file_names = $filter['items'] ;

        //Archive name
        $archive_file_name='files.zip';

        //Download Files path
        $file_path= getcwd(). '/content/';

        //cal the function
        zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path);
    } else {

        header("Refresh: 5; url= ./index.php ");
        print '<h1 style="text-align:center">You you shouldn\'t be here ......</pre>
        <p style="color: red;"><strong>redirection in 5 seconds</strong></p>
        <pre>';
        exit;
    }
```

When running this on a server and clicking the submit input that fires off to this php file I get

```
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for files.zip in /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php on line 13

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php:13) in /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php on line 14

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php:13) in /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php on line 15

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php:13) in /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php on line 16

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php:13) in /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php on line 17

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php:13) in /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php on line 18

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php:13) in /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php on line 19

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php:13) in /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php on line 20

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php:13) in /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php on line 21

Warning: readfile(files.zip) [function.readfile]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php on line 24

Warning: unlink(files.zip) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/grindkit/public_html/sdk/download.php on line 25
```

I've looked over StackOverflow and I'm getting more confused as to why it's happening rather than getting closer to fixing it. Any help would be great.

Comment: On the production server, is the file actually created after the `$zip->close` call? Maybe `die()` the script there and check if the file is present. If so, did you try without the `header content-length` line and without the `filesize` line? Just to make sure it works. Those lines aren't essential for downloading files, they just tell the browser how big files are so it can estimate download time.

Answer (score 0):

If this works locally - then likely there is nothing wrong with the code. The following points jump out, which may help.

1 - make sure you have error reporting turned off for this script, otherwise it will screw up the headers for the eventual download.

2 - It's probably not a file permission issue (writing) because it would fail on trying to create the archive.

3 - Have you taken a look at the output of your PHPInfo on your local machine and your server? Obviously look for a version difference first, but 5.3.x has been very problematic for me when developing in newer versions as a fair amount changed.

4 - What is returned from $zip->addFile ? I'm inclined to suggest that this is failing, so the zip file is empty / never written. I would take a look at the variables there for mistakes.

5 - Final thought and it may be wrong, but are you running the same OS on your test environments? Windows, for example, isn't case sensitive for file names, whilst Linux / Mac are.